Can you cross into another dimension
My partner committed suicide 2 weeks ago.
I have managed to visit him when I'm sleeping (dreaming) and when I see him everything is normal until I have to wake up and we are both saying how much we are going to miss each other because we know when I wake up he won't be there anymore.
This isn't every night I have lucid dreams about a lot of places. I would really love to see him more and possibly just cross over if I can to be with him all the time.

Is this question directly related to Buddhist teachings, philosophy and practice?

I'm so sorry to hear about your loss.

I have/had experiences like that too -- seeing my partner again and again seemed like an example or reminder of how experiences are "mind-made" (which is a Buddhist phrase or doctrine). I suppose that the experience of death has been the motivation for a lot of people, even starting with the Buddha himself, to understand "Buddhism".

suicide isn't an answer for suffering. It only increases the suffering. Only by understanding the nature of reality suffering can be ended.

No one can save from suffering but you yourself. If anyone would have been able to save you or somebody then we all would be willing to tread on "your" path which seems romantically spiritual. Focus on how to save yourself from suffering rather than seeking a physical or spiritual companionship. Since you have come to a Buddhist site , I am assuming you know about the Four Nobel Truths.
Know that this(birth , ageing and death,meeting with dislikable person,separation from likable person) is suffering. Know that there is an origin of suffering. Know that there is an end of suffering. Know that there is a path leading to the end of suffering.
Bring your friends to join you on the path leading to the end of suffering.

Your answer is good. But could elaborate around lucid dreams and results of suicide and how to avoid it. .

There are environments. Some enviroments believe in God and spirituality and lucid dreaming. Others lack faith in dreams , god etc. Do not read too much into it as all environments are impermanent. Suicide is not the end of life. There is a rebirth. Follow Buddha to end suffering.

I fell your loss. I too have had such a loss. The text of Mindfulness of Death (Donald Lopez, Religions of Tibet In Practice) was given to me not shortly thereafter.
No one, at anytime, anywhere, escapes the Lord of Death. We must wish them farewell, and strongly practice against clinging and attachment. Yet love and compassion never dies. It is part and parcel of the consciousness we all share. We are all impermanent beings. Not connecting to this universal Mind leaves us wandering in Samsara. The true reality is this: we are never separated from them, yet because of our current mental state, it isn't obvious. But Practice changes this.
Gratitude is the Key to Grief. Then when you feel they are close, you can express this Gratitude with an open heart. (Greater Good Science Center, University of California, Berkeley "Science of Happiness) I humbly offer this key to you in the same manner. It is very difficult Karma to bear, but there is no judgement, no fault, and no shame. (Jon Kabat-Zinn) Face this and all things as obstacles to overcome.
Every Day the grief lasts one day longer; as it grows, you too must grow. Even in sadness you can feel yourself eventually becoming stronger. Quite possibly stronger than anything you have ever felt. This is never easy. But the Path is here >----->
